# How do I pass a path with spaces to WSL for Windows Terminal

Tags: terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to start WSL at a specific path `/mnt/c/Users/My User/repos`. We can do `wsl.exe ~` for starting in the home directory, but I can't seem to pass a different path.

I can wrap the path into an escaped string, but WSL won't take a string as a default parameter, so `wsl.exe \"/mnt/c/Users/My User/repos\"` doesn't work.

There is no `-p` or `--path` option that accepts a string, and I have looked at the [WSL options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config)
and the WSL error/help CLI and haven't found a solution.

```json
{
    "colorScheme": "One Half Dark",
    "commandline": "wsl.exe '/mnt/c/Users/My User/repos' -d Ubuntu-20.04",
    "icon": "\ud83d\udc40",
    "name": "My Windows Terminal Profile",
    "tabTitle": "Windows Terminal"
}
```

I have tried with:

```
/mnt/c/Users/My\\ User/repos
'/mnt/c/Users/My\\ User/repos'
\"/mnt/c/Users/My\\ User/repos\"
```

and got `/bin/bash: /mnt/c/Users/My\ User/repos: No such file or directory`.

I have also tried `/mnt/c/Users/My\ User/repos` with no quotes, single quotes `'` and escaped double quotes `\"`
and the JSON parser says `Invalid escape character in string. [jsonc(261)]`.

Comment: Why doesn't double quotations, or `/mnt/c/Users/My\ User/repos`, work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I did try escaping the space as well and it didn't work. WSL just says "Is a directory" and exits with an error code.

Comment: Does escaping the way you showed in the question and escaping the way in my comment have the same result _(I'm unsure if Linux treats both ways the same and don't have a way to test at the moment)_?

Comment: Without quotations, it seems to be invalid since this would have to go inside a string / JSON config: https://imgur.com/a/L2t4l82

Comment: Shouldn't it be `wsl.exe '/mnt/c/Users/My\ User/repos' -d Ubuntu-20.04`? _(i.e. single quotes were missing)_

Comment: JW, no luck. JSON doesn't like the single backslash, and it didn't work when I escaped it either. I am curious of how to solve this, but the solution I posted is good enough for my use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit non-intuitive, and just as undocumented as the `~` option, but `wsl --cd` sounds like what you are looking for.  It actually takes a *Windows* path spec, not the WSL/Linux form.  So:

```
wsl --cd "C:\Users\My User\repos"
```

If you are using the Windows Terminal Settings UI, then it will automatically provide the proper quoting for you in the `settings.json`, which is:

```
{
  "commandline": "wsl --cd \"C:\\Users\\My User\\repos"",
  "name": "Profile Name"
}
```

And just for fun, here's an alternative, hacky method that you really shouldn't ever need to use, since the `--cd` option is the non-hacky, better way:

```
wsl --exec bash -c "cd /mnt/c/Users/My\ User/repos; exec bash"
```

While it's not the best option for this particular case, it does demonstrate the ability to edit the environment (`PWD` in this case) before exec'ing a shell.  That can be useful sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

[Self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

In the end, I did not manage to solve my problem the way I intended, but this works:

```json
{
    "commandline": "wsl.exe -d Ubuntu-20.04",
    "startingDirectory": "%USERPROFILE%/repos",
}
```